# Setting allowfullscreen attribute to a div tag

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

My question is pretty simple. Can I use the attribute `allowfullscreen="true"` to a normal `<div>` element to make it full-screen?

Actually, I'm building a custom YouTube Skin and I disabled the default controls using the Youtube iframe API and now, need to create new ones in place of them. But the problem is that making only the `<iframe>` element full screen does not allow me to place the new buttons (obviously outside of the `iframe`) in the fullscreen mode. So, please put some light in this matter.

P.S. - I have already tried putting the `allowfullscreen="true"` in the container `<div>` and it's working as of now. But is it the right process of doing what I have been trying to do?

Comment: You should be able to use the [Fullscreen API](https://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen).

Comment: Thanks for your precious reply :) :) @FabianSchultz

Comment: is this still working on the latest version of FireFox?

Comment: Yes. It's working and it should be working as it falls under the Fullscreen API. And to be frank, I have tried this on a new project less than a week ago and it's working as expected. @skydev

Comment: Thanks it does work, the issue is with the w3schools implementation of it on FireFox as seen here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_fullscreen